# got into an accident and car doesn't start - mazda 3

Tags: mazda-3

I'm not too familiar with cars. I got into accident and car doesn't start. Right after the accident, I was able to drive it for short distance til I found a parking spot where it completely stopped working after. At first steering wheel and battery lights were on. Now only check engine sign turns on when I try to start it. Before I take it to auto shop, I want to get more idea about the problem.  [Link1](https://streamable.com/qfcdi): here is a video showing I happen when I try to start it. [Link2](https://streamable.com/liwzn): a video showing the damaged parts.

[image: damaged part]

Comment: Assuming you are insured, your insurance company's damage  assessor will want to look at it BEFORE you get any work done, and will then take over the process of getting it repaired if they are going to pay for it. If you bent the subframe or the front suspension mount points, fixing the engine will be irrelevant if  the whole car is an insurance writeoff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whether or not the car starts is irrelevant. It won't be legal to drive anywhere, insurers are going to want an assessment, and judging by the pictures I'd place bets on it being a likely writeoff

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the engine not starting; that's the least of your problems. That car needs a lot of work, if it's even worth fixing; given the broken radiator support, I'd say that it needs to go on a frame for straightening. Call your insurance, tell them where the car is, and let them sort everything else out.

Comment: Nah . . . merely a *flesh wound* . . .   =8-O